# viewWillAppear: method doesn't seem to respond while using tab bar and navigation controllers together

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am using Tab bar + navigation based application and I have 4 tab bars. When I navigate from one view controller to another view controller, the `viewWillAppear:` method doesn't seem to respond and I am being forced to call it manually by creating the object of the next view controller. So my question is, how do I avoid calling the `viewWillAppear:` method manually whenever I navigate from one view controller to another? Instead, it should get triggered automatically just like the `viewdidLoad:` method gets triggered when you navigate from one view controller to other. Please guide me on how could I do that.

Hoping for the best possible Answer
Thanks in Advance

Comment: When you say viewWillAppear: you mean viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated function. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, viewWillAppear is a little special, it is usually called automatically but in some cases including when you are adding a view controllers view manually (view addSubview:), and also when adding this as a view controller to a `UITabBarController` or `UINavigationCnotroller` (of which you have both !) it doesn't get messaged.

This however is only for the root view, as you navigate (maybe with a navigation controller) back and forth, that root view's viewWillAppear will get triggered as some point.

In short, if you need to implement something in viewWillAppear in these cases, you should message it yourself when you know it's going to be presented. You can handle this case in your view controller, check out the following article about the matter:

http://www.touchthatfruit.com/viewwillappear-and-viewdidappear-not-being-ca

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In some apps that have a tab bar controller, each tab also needs a nav controller before a view can be added:

```
[[[_mainTabController topViewController] navigationController] pushViewController:renewalScreen animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check [UITabBarDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITabBarDelegate) then look for the method:

`- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item`.

> **Description:** Sent to the delegate when the user selects a tab bar
>   item.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 4 tab items on a tab bar, rather than '4 tab bars'?  If you have a tab bar with tab items, the `viewWillAppear:` methods absolutely should be called by the system as the tabs are selected by the user.  You could have other issues that are causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't forget to call [super viewWillAppear] somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the viewDidAppear method instead.